# Table do PrimeNG não aparece

Tags: javascript, angular

Saudação galera. Estou tentando usar a *Table* do PrimeNG, mas estou com dificuldades. Segui os passos na *Get Started* e a *Table* não aparece no navegador. E para piorar, não consta nenhum erro no console do navegado e nem do código.

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "comercial-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeflex": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "comercial-ui": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/comercial-ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "comercial-ui:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "comercial-ui:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "comercial-ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "comercial-ui-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "comercial-ui:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "comercial-ui:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "comercial-ui"
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PainelNegociacaoComponent } from './painel-negociacao/painel-negociacao.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PainelNegociacaoComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TableModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**oportunidade.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OportunidadeService {

  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/oportunidades';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  listar(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl);
  }

}
```

**painel.negociacao.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OportunidadeService } from '../oportunidade.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-painel-negociacao',
  templateUrl: './painel-negociacao.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./painel-negociacao.component.css']
})
export class PainelNegociacaoComponent implements OnInit {

  oportunidades = [];

  constructor(private oportunidadeService: OportunidadeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.oportunidadeService.listar().subscribe(resposta => this.oportunidades = <any> resposta);
  }

}
```

**painel-negociacao.component.html**

```html
<p-table [value]="oportunidades">
    <ng-template pTemplete="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Prospecto</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template value="body" let-oportunidade>
        <tr>
            <td>{{oportunidade.descricao}}</td>
            <td>{{oportunidade.nomeProspecto}}</td>
            <td>{{oportunidade.valor}}</td>
        </tr>

    </ng-template>
  
</p-table>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-painel-negociacao></app-painel-negociacao>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu painel-navegacaoComponent.html apresenta alguns erros de digitação:

mude:

```
<ng-template pTemplete="header">
```

para:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
```

e:

```
<ng-template value="body" let-oportunidade>
```

para:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-oportunidade>
```

Comment: João, obrigado!